# $I,J$ are $p$-primary ideals, but $I+J$ is not

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ideals

I asked this question on the stack exchange, and after no answers and the recommendation of someone else, I am posting it here on MO. I am looking for an example of two ideals $I$ and $J$ in a noetherian ring that are both primary to $p$, but their sum is not. There are a few things that I do know: If $p$ is maximal, there are no examples (ruling out the artinian case). If $I+J$ is unmixed, then it will be $p$-primary (because $p$ is a minimal prime of $I+J$). Also, if $I$ and $J$ are monomial ideals, then $I+J$ will be $p$-primary, because primary ideals have the same form for monomial ideals.

Comment: Math.SE post: [Example where $I,J$ are $p$-primary ideals, but $I+J$ is not $p$-primary.](//math.stackexchange.com/q/2074318).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $R$ be the commutative ring $k[x,y,z]$.  Let $I$ be the ideal generated by the regular sequence $(x^2,y)$.  Let $J$ be the ideal generated by the regular sequence $(x^2,y-xz)$.  Then both $R/I$ and $R/J$ are Cohen-Macaulay, hence unmixed.  The prime $\mathfrak{p}=\langle x,y \rangle$ is the unique associated prime of both $I$ and $J$.  However, $I+J$ equals $\langle x^2,xz,y\rangle$, and this ideal also has $\mathfrak{m}=\langle x,y,z\rangle$ as an associated prime.  Indeed, $\mathfrak{m}$ is the annihilator of $\overline{x}$ in the quotient ring $R/(I+J)$.

Comment: In fact, $\langle x^2,xz,y\rangle=\langle x,y\rangle\cap\langle x^2,y,z\rangle$ is a primary decomposition.

Comment: Geometric intuition: $I$ and $J$ are thickenings of the line $\sqrt{I}=\sqrt{J}$ to two different ribbons, that intersect transversely as $\sqrt{I}$ away from $\vec 0$, where they're tangent to one another and the intersection is big. Nice example!

Comment: @AllenKnutson.  Yes, you are correct.  That is precisely how I came up with this example.